# RWD theme: Making search bar permanent

Tags: catalogsearch, rwd-theme, rwd

I'm using the RWD theme and am trying to make the search bar permanent (rather than clicking the search icon and having it appear). I'm still a newbie and am poking through the template files looking for some Javascript that will make this happen, as well as looking through the SCSS to see if I can find something acting on the id or class (seems to be either #header-search or .skip-links), but I can't seem to find anything.

Any hints on where to go next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is looking to do this, I ended up finding the Javascript file (app.js) in the RWD theme that's responsible for hiding the search bar. It adds and removes a 'skip-active' class to show or hide the search bar, so I added this script to the header template of my theme and achieved the desired effect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(function($){
    $('#header-search').addClass('skip-active');

 });

 </script>
```